# Convertion of tflite model to ONNX model

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, onnx

I have a tflite model and i want to convert it into tensorflow or keras or ONNX format. Is there a way?

I can import it using tf interpreter and run it on python. However i want to convert it into one of the above formats.

```
import tensorflow as tf
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="conv_actions_frozen.tflite")
tensors = interpreter.get_tensor_details()
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution?  I have the same problem because I want to run a tflite model in tfjs.

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Now there is converter to convert tflite models to onnx format. Install the tflite2onnx library.
All you have to do is :

```
import tflite2onnx

tflite_path = "path/to/the/tflitemodel"
onnx_path = "path/where/you/want/to/save/your/model" #modelname.onnx


tflite2onnx.convert(tflite_path,onnx_path)
```